# Trying to understand setting content providers in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I wanna change APN settings in a phone. Looked the api and there is a content provider named ACTION_APN_SETTINGS

developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APN_SETTINGS

but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to use it. Is there any example or something that does not involve the "contacts" content provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the source code of the [Android project](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/).

I guess [this](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/source/browse/src/com/google/code/apndroid/ApnDao.java) is the code that you are looking for.